# Bootstrap form input labels need to be inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form using bootstrap css, and I need  the labels to appear inline with the input fields, Usually this happens automatically and this time it has not can anyone help?

```
<style>

    #form-inpt{
        width: 200px;
    }

</style>

<form>

    <!-- Name and email -->
    <label>Name</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
    <label>Email Address</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="email">

    <!-- Business information -->
    <label>Company Name</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="CompanyName">
    <label>Company Phone Number</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="CompanyPhone">
    <label>Address Line 1</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Address1">
    <label>Address Line 2</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Address2">
    <label>Address Line 3</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Address3">
    <label>Town</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Town">
    <label>County</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="County">
    <label>Post Code</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="PostCode">
    <label>Opening Hours</label><textarea id="form-inpt" class="form-control" name="OpeningHours"></textarea>
    <label>Website</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Website">

    <!-- Google map coordinates -->
    <label>Longitude</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Longitude">
    <label>Latitude</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Latitude">

    <!-- Anti spam -->
    <label>Anti Spam, What is 9+1?</label><input id="form-inpt" class="form-control" type="text" name="Spam">

    <!-- Button -->
    <label>Submit</label><input class="form-control" type="submit" value="submit" style="width: 200px;>

</form>
```

Comment: Seriously? You might want to show us your css or better still create a bootply - psychic we ain't

Comment: Well, this is it...http://www.bootply.com/GGZfOQh0ee

Comment: you cannot have same id for multiple elements. They should be unique!! `form-inpt` is repeating for all the inputs.. Use class instead..

Comment: I realise this, but changing them does not solve the issue

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/82900 try this

Comment: I was afraid that I would have to go the long way around, oh well this appears to be the best solution so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use bootstrap div classes like,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <label Id="1">...</label><input ...../>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label Id= "2">...</label><input ...../>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to fix the problem

Comment: As per 'Rao' said in comments, you have to use different ids for every input.